# File manager opens automatically after booting

Tags: kubuntu

The file manager starts off just after login.  It keeps on opening different windows, none of them opens up, neither can I kill using ps -e.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2):

"system settings"-> "startup and shutdown" -> "session management" -> "on login" -> "start with an empty session"

Hope this helps.